# Can't retrieve JSON data from POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a simple Node.js web server and I have troubles with sending requests to the server. Here's an example with a simple html "form". I send a stringified JSON data, but the `req.body` is empty.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" id="field" value="foo">
        <button type="button" id="button">bar</button>

        <script>
            addElement = function()  {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '/database');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

                var newElem = new Object();
                newElem.name = field.value || "";
                var requestData = JSON.stringify(newElem);
                console.log(newElem);
          // {name: "foo"}
                xhr.send(requestData);
            }

            button.onclick = addElement;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Node Server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname +"/index.html");
});

app.post('/database', function(req, res) {
    console.log("req.body = ", req.body);

//expected output: req.body = ({name: foo})
//actual output: req.body = ()

});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on ' + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `contentType` to `Content-Type`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `contentType` to `Content-Type`.

[Mozilla Content-Type Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send the request to server. first u need to add the server Url.

**for Example**

In case your server application is running in 3000 means then u change

xhr.open('POST', '/database'); to xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/database');

the following code has :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="text" id="field" value="foo">
        <button type="button" id="button">bar</button>

        <script>
            addElement = function()  {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/database');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

                var newElem = new Object();
                newElem.name = field.value || "";
                var requestData = JSON.stringify(newElem);
                console.log(newElem);
          // {name: "foo"}
                xhr.send(requestData);
            }

            button.onclick = addElement;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to add the server URL or Port since the express app is serving the html file and so the browser adds the server url+port automatically. Your code won't work as well, because instead of 'contentType' it has to be 'Content-Type'